# Good Answer Badge not awarded

Tags: support, badges

Per my understanding of the description of the Good Answer silver badge, it is awarded when your answer gets a score of 25 or more

I have score of 25 on 2 answers:

[Setting the Api Version with Swagger UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783349/setting-the-api-version-with-swagger-ui/35790642#35790642)

[JBoss is not creating JNDI for EJB 2.0 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34742597/jboss-is-not-creating-jndi-for-ejb-2-0-project/35554698#35554698)

But I have not been rewarded the badge. Am I missing something?

Comment: Those answers have a score of _1_.

Comment: Ok. So the +25 i see on my profile for the answer is not the score, but the gained reputation?

Comment: What is the difference between score and reputation? Does score correspond to number of upvotes?

Comment: [What is the difference between score and reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106927/what-is-the-difference-between-score-and-reputation)

Answer (score 5):

Ok. So score and reputation are two different things -

[What is the difference between score and reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106927/what-is-the-difference-between-score-and-reputation)

Score = number of upvotes - number of downvotes

Answer (score 0):

`Silver Badge` description :  " **Answer score of 25 or more**"   That means Your Individual answer must gain score of 25 to earn badge. it's not depend on your total reputation.